# Excel VBA: How to transfer data to another sheet if not found?

Tags: excel, if-statement, while-loop, vba

I have three sheets in Excel. Data Sheet, Roles Sheet and Report Sheet.

The program is gonna lookup the data of Data Sheet to Roles Sheet. If the data is not found in the Role Sheet, that data will be copied to Rerport sheet.

But my program has a problem on getting the right data to Report Sheet. It transfers all the data from Data Sheet to Report sheet.

```
Dim iRowRoleSummary As Integer
Dim sGetRoleData As String
Dim sGetRoleValid As String
Dim sGetRoleSummary As String

iRowCountData = 2
iRowCountValidRoles = 2
iRowRoleSummary = 2

While Sheets("Data").Cells(iRowCountData, 2) <> ""

    While Sheets("Approved Roles List").Cells(iRowCountValidRoles, 1) <> ""
        If Sheets("Data").Cells(iRowCountData, 2) <> Sheets("Approved Roles List").Cells(iRowCountValidRoles, 1) Then
            sGetRoleSummary = Sheets("Data").Cells(iRowCountData, 2)
            Sheets("Report Role Summary").Cells(iRowRoleSummary, 1) = sGetRoleSummary
        End If
        iRowCountValidRoles = iRowCountValidRoles + 1
    Wend
    iRowCountData = iRowCountData + 1
    iRowRoleSummary = iRowRoleSummary + 1
    iRowCountValidRoles = 2
Wend
```

Comment: code looks okay from what I can tell. Is there something in your data that makes the two sheets look equal, but in fact are not equal, i.e. - extra spaces or something of that nature?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the logic. But don't you have to compare each `Data` row with **each** `Role` row **before** you can tell whether this data row needs to be transferred to the report sheet? Currently, the program just compares each data row to the first `Role` row, sees that they are not the same and moves it to report. If I am not mistaken, the code never gets beyond row 2 on the role sheet. Why don't you insert a `Debug.Print iRowCountValidRoles` to verify my assumption.

Comment: Can't say this is the cause, but your code's risky because you're comparing Value against Value. If, for example, the two sheets have a different format then a comparison of identical values with different formats will return false. I'd add `.Value2` after each `Cell` reference, if for nothing else than to eliminate the risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting all comments into a solution proposal:

```
Dim iRowRoleSummary As Integer
Dim sGetRoleData As String
Dim sGetRoleValid As String
Dim sGetRoleSummary As String
Dim bolFound As Boolean

iRowCountData = 2
iRowCountValidRoles = 2
iRowRoleSummary = 2

While Sheets("Data").Cells(iRowCountData, 2) <> ""
    bolFound = False
    While Sheets("Approved Roles List").Cells(iRowCountValidRoles, 1) <> ""
        If Trim(Sheets("Data").Cells(iRowCountData, 2).Value2) = Trim(Sheets("Approved Roles List").Cells(iRowCountValidRoles, 1).Value2) Then
            bolFound = True
        End If
        iRowCountValidRoles = iRowCountValidRoles + 1
    Wend

    sGetRoleSummary = Sheets("Data").Cells(iRowCountData, 2).Value2
    If bolFound = False Then
        'Transfer to Report Role sheet
        Sheets("Report Role Summary").Cells(iRowRoleSummary, 1).Value2 = sGetRoleSummary
        iRowRoleSummary = iRowRoleSummary + 1
    Else
        'Not sure what the code is for this part
    End If
    iRowCountData = iRowCountData + 1
    iRowCountValidRoles = 2
Wend
```

An alternative method might be the follow:

```
Dim iRowRoleSummary As Integer
Dim sGetRoleData As String
Dim sGetRoleValid As String
Dim sGetRoleSummary As String
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim varFound As Variant

lngLastRow = Sheets("Approved Roles List").Cells(Sheets("Approved Roles List").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

With Sheets("Data")
    For iRowCountData = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If Trim(.Cells(iRowCountData, 2).Value2) <> vbNullString Then
            sGetRoleSummary = Trim(Sheets("Data").Cells(iRowCountData, 2).Value2)
            Set varFound = Worksheets("Approved Roles List").Range("B2:B" & lngLastRow).Find(What:=sGetRoleSummary, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
            If Not varFound Is Nothing Then
                'Transfer to one sheet
                iRowCountValidRoles = iRowCountValidRoles + 1
            Else
                'Transfer to the other sheet
                iRowRoleSummary = iRowRoleSummary + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next iRowCountData
End With
```

Note, that neither code has been tested. So, you might still encounter one or two bumps in the road.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion and all, but this is a task better suited to vlookups and if statements...

Use a vlookup to see if the data exists in the second sheet: =vlookup(A1,Roles!A:A,1)

Then in the third sheet have an if statement: =if(Data!A1<>"",Data!A1,"")

Copy and paste the values in the third sheet as values, and you are done. Easier than messing with the VBA code. [I assumed Sheet1 is named Data and Sheet2 is Roles]